# Haskell pattern matching in safeTail function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I got a Haskell function that is defined using pattern matching but i'm not really understand why is it looks like the way it is.

```
safeTail (x : xs) = xs
```

I'm not really understand specifically at the (x : xs), what does it mean ?

Comment: If that's the full definition of the function, I would have named that `unsafeTail` or `dangerousTail`, since that will crash on the empty list.

Comment: I got the catchall for the empty list but decided not to put it here because the main point here is that I don't understand the syntax of (x:xs) and not the function.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a similar definition for a list data type.

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)  -- (1)
```

There are two constructors: one to create an empty list, and another to create a list given a value and another list.

Pattern matching works by matching a value against the constructor used to create it.

```
safeTail (Cons x xs) = xs  -- (2)
```

That is, if `safeTail` is applied to a value defined using the `Cons` constructor, then the return value is the second argument to `Cons`.

In real code, both the type constructor `List` and the `Empty` data constructor are named `[]` and the `Cons` constructor is named `(:)`.

```
data [] a = [] | (:) a ([] a)
```

which Haskell allows to be written with special syntax

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Applying the type constructer `[]` to a type or type variable can be replaced by including the argument inside the `[]`, and the symbolic constructor (because it starts with a `:`) can be used as an infix operator.

That is, you could write

```
safeTail ((:) x xs) = xs  -- (3)
```

or

```
safeTail (x : xs) = xs  -- (4)
```

with (2), (3), and (4) being equivalent to (1) above.

```
>>> safeTail ((:) 3 ((:) 2 ((:) 1 [])))
[2,1]
>>> safeTail (3:2:1:[])
[2,1]
>>> safeTail [3,2,1]
[2,1]
```

For further simplicity, Haskell represents `(x:[])` as `[x]`, `(x:y:[])` as `[x,y]`, etc.

A complete definition of `safeTail` would also provide a value for an empty list argument:

```
safeTail [] = []
```

or a `Maybe`-based definition

```
safeTail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeTail [] = Nothing
safeTail (x:xs) = Just xs
```

Comment: The `Maybe`-based definition is actually a `safeHead` and not a `safeTail`

Answer (score 1):

Thats the pattern matching.

The first argument to your function `safeTail` is some list type. In case the argument is a non-empty list, this pattern matching will succeed and bind the `x` to the head element and `xs` to the tail of the list.

In case you pass an empty list to `safeTail` the pattern match will fail and other patterns (if any exists) are checked.